# Creating a Soundboard with Twilio

Tags: audio, twilio, twilio-api

Right on Twilios website it claims: `using Twilio Client’s two-way audio pipe: soundboards, audio recorders, in-game chat, and much more.`-
https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-client/what-can-i-build-with-twilio-client

However I cannot find in their documentation how to go about playing a sound during a live call. Does anyone know how to go about playing a sound file during a live call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To play arbitrary sounds during live call for fun or profit I would either use [modifying live call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state) by posting to call url or have a bit more flexibility with [Conference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference). I'll describe it for the call option (it is less flexible as it allows only up to 2 participants).

1. [Make a call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls) by `POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Calls`
2. Remember the CallSid - either from the call POST request or subsequent callbacks to your Voice callback url
3. Have a publicly available url that returns TwiML which can be used to play the sounds you want.
4. [Modify call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state) by `POST /2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Calls/{CallSid}` You can force the ongoing call to request new TwiML from the previous url. The returned TwiML can be used to hang up a call, play some audio files (as described by @philnash) etc.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can play sound files during live calls using the [`<Play>` verb in TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play).

For example, here's how to play a cowbell 10 times:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Play loop="10">https://api.twilio.com/cowbell.mp3</Play>
</Response>
```

Let me know if that helps at all.